# Copy Directory/Folder Program Error (Java)

Tags: java, file, netbeans, mkdir

I was wondering if anyone could help me with my program since I do not know where I went wrong with writing it. My steps for the program are as follows:

1. Ask the user for the source directory and a destination.  The source is the directory to be copied; the destination is the directory that will be the parent of the new copy.
2. First your program should make a new directory in the new location with the same name as the source directory.  (You may need to do something special for root directories if you are copying an entire disk.  A root directory has no parent directory, and often, no name.)
3. Then your program should create an array with File class objects for each item in the contents of the source directory
4. Next , it should iterate the array, and  for each item in the array
   1.if it is a file, copy the file to the new directory using the copyFile() method

   2. if it is a directory, recursively call this method to copy the directory and all of its contents.

My code is as following, I do not understand what I did wrong with this program but no matter what the output ends up being "file does not exist."

```html
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DirectCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
   
    //Create a new instance of scanner to get user input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Ask user to input the directory to be copied
    System.out.print("Input directory to be copied.");

    //Save input as String
    String dirName = scanner.nextLine();

    //Ask user to input destination where direction will be copied
    System.out.print("Input destination directory will be moved to.");

    //Save input as String
    String destName = scanner.nextLine();

    //Run method to determine if it is a directory or file
    isDirFile(dirName, destName);


}//end main

public static void isDirFile (String source, String dest) throws Exception{
    //Create a File object for new directory in new location with same name
    //as source directory
    File dirFile = new File (dest + source);

    //Make the new directory
    dirFile.mkdirs();

    //Create an array of File class objects for each item in the source
    //directory
    File[] entries; 

    //If source directory exists
    if (dirFile.exists()){
        //If the source directory is a directory
        if (dirFile.isDirectory()){

            //Get the data and load the array
            entries = dirFile.listFiles();

            //Iterate the array using alternate for statement
            for (File entry : entries){
                if (entry.isFile()){
                    copyFile (entry.getAbsolutePath(), dest);
                } //end if
                else {
                    isDirFile (entry.getAbsolutePath(), dest);
                }  //end else if
            }//end for
        }//end if
    }//end if
    else {
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
    } //end else
}

public static void copyFile (String source, String dest) throws Exception {

    //declare Files
    File sourceFile = null;
    File destFile = null;

    //declare stream variables
    FileInputStream sourceStream = null;
    FileOutputStream destStream = null;

    //declare buffering variables
    BufferedInputStream bufferedSource = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedDest = null;

    try {
        //Create File objects for source and destination files
        sourceFile = new File (source);
        destFile = new File (dest);

        //Create file streams for the source and destination
        sourceStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        destStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

        //Buffer the file streams with a buffer size of 8k
        bufferedSource = new BufferedInputStream(sourceStream,8182);
        bufferedDest = new BufferedOutputStream(destStream,8182);

        //Use an integer to transfer data between files
        int transfer;

        //Alert user as to what is happening
        System.out.println("Beginning file copy:");
        System.out.println("\tCopying " + source);
        System.out.println("\tTo      " + dest);

        //Read a byte while checking for End of File (EOF)
        while ((transfer = bufferedSource.read()) !=-1){

        //Write a byte
        bufferedDest.write(transfer);
    }//end while

    }//end try

    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("An unexpected I/O error occurred.");
    }//end catch

    finally {
        //close file streams
        if (bufferedSource !=null)
            bufferedSource.close();

        if (bufferedDest !=null)
            bufferedDest.close();

        System.out.println("Your files have been copied correctly and "
                + "closed.");
    }//end finally
}//end copyDir

}//end class
```

Comment: Could you put and an example of what you put in dirName and destName ? I don't understand why you try to iterate on a folder you just create. And i don't understand why you try to create a folder with dest+source, it can't work if both are absolute path.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. What happened with the (dest + source) thing was that my professor wrote a mistake for the requirements. I knew it was weird but at the moment I was doing what he told.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `source` and `dest` are something of the like `C:\` and `D:\New Dest`, the problem *might* lie within this line: `File dirFile = new File (dest + source);`.

According to the [`JavaDoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html), that constructor will resemble a file which is the concatenation of the two strings. In the example above, that would yield something like `D:\New Dest\C:`.

The code below does not fail:

```
    File a = new File("C:" + "D:\\New Dest");
    a.mkdirs();
    System.out.println(a.getAbsolutePath());
```

However, no directories seem to be created. I think that what you need to do, is to rename this: `File dirFile = new File (dest + source);` to something like this:

```
File dirFile = new File (dest, new File(source).getName());
```

It should create the directory structure you are after. Note that `getName()` will be empty for root directories.

EDIT: As per your comment, and as @vincent mentioned, you are are creating a new directory, calling it `dirFile` where you will place a copy of the same directory structure specified by `source`. The *problem* is this: `entries = dirFile.listFiles();`. You are saying that the source of your directory structure is the new file you have created, which should be empty, thus, `entries` should be an empty array.

Since the array is empty, the `for` loop will exit immediately (it will not execute at all). You will need to replace this line: `entries = dirFile.listFiles();` with something like so: `entries = new File(source).listFiles();`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the program copies the folder to the new destination but for some reason it doesn't bring the contents from within that directory to the new one. Can you also help me with that?

Comment: Hey I was wondering if it was any possible way I could message you because I'm noticing that the program for some reason does not call the copyFile method.

Comment: @Ricardo3: I have modified my answer to tackle your question. If you have any further issues, please let me know.